# SQL 3 week avearage with Multiple When in a Case Statement

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a 3 week average that is only calculated when the date is equal to today. Essentially the code would work like the one below but of course the one below is not correct. It says there is an incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'. Any guidance would be phenomenal.

```
CASE WHEN 
*Variable Name(Date)* = GETDATE()
THEN
CASE WHEN *Variable Name(Date)* >= GETDATE()-21 AND *Variable Name(Date)* < GETDATE()
THEN
SUM(*Variable Name(Minutes)*/3 ELSE 0 END AS ThreeWeekAvg
```

Comment: How is *Variable Name(Date)* going to be both equal to GetDate() **and** less than GetDate()?

Comment: @blorgbeard I need it to first identify that today is = to Getdate(). once that is known, the second part is to take the dates 21 days before the getdate up to just before the getdate and average them. Doing away with the first part would mean that every date is given a 3 week average when I only want it for the getdate

Comment: Your pseudo-code is confusing. Could you post a small sample table and expected output? That would probably be the easier way to clarify what you want.

Comment: Is this a step in a stored procedure or are you computing a column in a result set?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    ...
from
    <your table> t
    cross apply (
        select sum(minutes) / 3e as ThreeWeekAvg
        from <your table> t2
        where
                 t.<date> = cast(getdate() as date)
            and t2.<date> >= dateadd(day, -21, t.<date>)
            and t2.<date> < t.<date>
    );
```

By "variable name" I presume you're talking about columns. You could also use `sum() over (range ...)` on new versions of SQL Server.

Although I believe my attempt above it valid, here's another approach with a subquery that looks closer to why you were trying:

```
select
    ...
    case when *Variable Name(Date)* = getdate() then (
        select sum(*Variable Name(Minutes)*) / 3e
        from ...
        where *Variable Name(Date)* >= getdate() - 21 and *Variable Name(Date)* < getdate()
    ) as ThreeWeekAvg
from
    ...
```